# Aptana Studio 3 with PHP - constant indexing

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 with several big PHP projects (10.000+ files) and it suffers from very slow indexing of PHP files.... which takes 10-20 minutes to complete and starts every time at the startup of Aptana, and also sometimes at random moments, for example when synchronizing with SVN...

In the progress view I get multiple 'Indexing new PHP Modules' items. 
All the time it is doing this Aptana is unusably slow. I don't get why this indexing starts over and over again on files that aren't new at all!

I already turned off automatic refreshes and automatic build. If I exclude 'PHP' from the 'Project Natures' in the properties of the projects, the indexing stops, but then I don't have code completion in PHP files.

I cleaned all projects, created a new workspace, etc. and nothing helps... This happens on multiple pc's (Windows) so I guess more people get this behaviour.

Any possible solutions?

***UPDATE***

I added the folder of my workspace to the 'ignore'-folders of my virus scanner (Microsoft Security Essentials). At first this seemed to work, but then the indexing started again...

Comment: Have you tried eclipse w/ PDT? I know this is not the answer you are looking for but I experience a lot of bugs and slowdowns with Aptana that were solved by moving over to eclipse. Its the same interface even.

Comment: Yeah, tried that too... even tried Aptana with PDT... but with PDT I get 'DLTK indexing' all the time... kind of the same problem, I guess... I know my prjects are big, but I just don't get why all this indexing can't be turned on/off for certain folders... and why it starts again and again...!

Comment: Have you tried excluding dirs/files from the *Buildpath*? I do that in PDT from time to time, files/dirs excluded from the *PHP Buildpath* aren't indexed. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Aptana uses that indexing to scan your files for it's auto-complete feature. in effect, it makes your PC slow, that's the trade-off of having such features. I myself have departed from Aptana, especially when using a slow PC. The fact that it runs on eclipse (which runs on JAVA) makes it slow, plus some other features that are just bloat (like the built-in GIT that does not work).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you did the right steps to try and resolve it, and it also seems we should have a ticket for that, so I created one at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4500 (please add yourself as a 'watcher').

One more thing to try is to break down a big project into a few smaller ones (whenever possible, of course). The indexer creates a binary index file for each project, and this file size is proportional to amount of classes, functions, variables and constants you have in your project. In case, for some reason (e.g. a bug) this file gets corrupted, a re-index will happen, so having multiple smaller projects may help with that. Again... just an idea.